# numpy histogram with 3x3D arrays as indices

Tags: python, numpy

I've got 3x3D arrays which are the red, green and blue channels of a 3D rgb image. What is an elegant way in numpy to to create a histogram volume of the input channels?

The operation would be equivalent to

```
""" assume R, G and B are 3D arrays and output is a 3D array filled with zeros """
for x in x_dim:
     for y in y_dim:
          for z in z_dim:
               output[ R[x][y][z] ][ G[x][y][z] ][ B[x][y][z] ] += 1
```

This code too slow for large images. Can numpy improve the efficiency of the above algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `numpy.histogramdd` but, as you say, the method proposed by @jozzas won't work. What you have to do is flatten each of your three 3D arrays and then combine them into a 2-d array of dimensions `(x_dim*y_dim*z_dim, 3)`, which you pass to `histogramdd`. The fact that your original data are 3D is a red herring, since the spatial information is irrelevant to calculating the histogram.

Here is an example using random data in the channel cubes:

```
import numpy 

n = 400  # approximate largest cube size that works on my laptop
# Fill channel cubes with random 8-bit integers
r = numpy.random.randint(256, size=(n,n,n)).astype(numpy.uint8)
g = numpy.random.randint(256, size=(n,n,n)).astype(numpy.uint8)
b = numpy.random.randint(256, size=(n,n,n)).astype(numpy.uint8)

# reorder data into for suitable for histogramming
data = numpy.vstack((r.flat, g.flat, b.flat)).astype(numpy.uint8).T

# Destroy originals to save space
del(r); del(g); del(b)

m = 256                                  # size of 3d histogram cube
hist, edges = numpy.histogramdd(
    data, bins=m, range=((-0.5,255.5),(-0.5,255.5),(-0.5,255.5))
    )

# Check that it worked
assert hist.sum() == n**3, 'Failed to conserve pixels'
```

This does use a lot more memory than you would expect because `histogramdd` seems to be using 64-bit floats to do its work, even though we are sending it 8-bit integers.

Comment: What will the output of such a procedure yield? I'm imagining output where `output[x,y,z]` is the count of `R[:]==x and G[:]==y and B[:]==z`. Is it something at all like this?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. I get the impression that your input channel arrays are integers, in which case you can specify `bins=N` and `range=((0,N-1),(0,N-1),(0,N-1))`, where `N` is the number of discrete pixel values (e.g., `N=256` for 8 bits per channel). However, unless `x_dim`, etc are much larger than `N`, then I imagine this will give you a rather sparse and noisy histogram. So you might want to set the `bins` parameter to a smaller value. For more details, see the docs for `histogramdd`

Comment: This works, except only on input arrays smaller than 40x40x40... any idea why that might be?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include example code. I can get it to work on arrays up to 400x400x400 on a machine with very little free memory. This took 30 sec of CPU time and the python process seemed to max out at about 1.5GB memory usage. How big are your arrays?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao That is so that the integers fall in the center of each bin

Comment: @AlvaroJoao In other words, `-0.5` is the left edge of the first bin, and `255.5` is the right edge of the last bin

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 8-bit channels, the 3-tuple of integers (R,G,B) can be thought of as a single number in base 256: `R*256**2 + G*256 + B`. Thus we can convert the 3 arrays R,G,B into a single array of "color values" and use `np.bincount` to produce the desired histogram.

```
import numpy as np

def using_bincount(r,g,b):
    r=r.ravel().astype('int32')
    g=g.ravel().astype('int32')
    b=b.ravel().astype('int32')
    output=np.zeros((base*base*base),dtype='int32')
    result=np.bincount(r*base**2+g*base+b)
    output[:len(result)]+=result
    output=output.reshape((base,base,base))
    return output

def using_histogramdd(r,g,b):
    data = np.vstack((r.flat, g.flat, b.flat)).astype(np.uint8).T
    del(r); del(g); del(b)
    hist, edges = np.histogramdd(
        data, bins=base, range=([0,base],[0,base],[0,base])
        )
    return hist

np.random.seed(0)
n = 200
base = 256
r = np.random.randint(base, size=(n,n,n)).astype(np.uint8)
g = np.random.randint(base, size=(n,n,n)).astype(np.uint8)
b = np.random.randint(base, size=(n,n,n)).astype(np.uint8)

if __name__=='__main__':
    bhist=using_bincount(r,g,b)
    hhist=using_histogramdd(r,g,b)
    assert np.allclose(bhist,hhist)
```

These timeit results suggest using_bincount is faster than using_histogramdd, perhaps because histogramdd is built for handling floats and bins which are ranges, while bincount is solely for counting integers.

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_bincount(test.r,test.g,test.b)'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.07 sec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_histogramdd(test.r,test.g,test.b)'
10 loops, best of 3: 8.42 sec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy's `histogramdd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html#numpy.histogramdd) to compute the histogram of an n-dimensional array. If you don't want a histogram for each 2d slice, be sure to set the `bins` for that dimension to 1.

To get the overall histogram, you could compute them individually for the R, G and B channels and then take the maximum value of the three for each position.

Comment: I like the idea of using histogramdd and just setting the bins to 1 for a dimension you don't need to use.  I don't know where, but I'm going to use that.  +1

Comment: The information that needs to come out is the values of each inputs _at corresponding indices_. I don't understand how you can compute the histograms for each channel individually and keep any notion of, for example, (1,1,1) aligning on each input.